Good "hash_func" for unhashable items in streamlit's st.cache_resource - mainly dataframes?
Streamlit's st.cache_resource decorator is key to speeding up streamlit apps.
In functions like:
@st.cache_resource
def slow_function(inputA, input_b): 
   ...
   return something

it can speed up the code through memoization.
However, this relies on all the inputs being "hashable". If the input itself does not implement the __hash__ dunder method, then the user can provide a hashing function.

class myCustomType:
   ...

@st.cache_resource(hash_funcs={myCustomType: lambda obj: ___})
def slow_function(input_a:int, input_b:myCustomType): 
   ...
   return something

My question is what "general" hash functions could be used, specifically for inputs such as pandas or polars dataframes.
I've tried:
hash_funcs={pl.DataFrame: lambda obj: id(obj)} # Not stable across page re-execution
hash_funcs={pl.DataFrame: lambda obj: f'{obj.shape} {obj.schema}} # Not confident it's unique
hash_funcs={pl.DataFrame: lambda obj: hash_all_cells(obj) } # too slow

Are there other solutions that could be applied here?

The dataframe shouldn't be an input. The input is going to be a date or a file or whatever that's coming from the UI. I'm guessing you want to cache the dataframe that you loaded to answer Q1 b/c the same data might be useful for Q2. For that you'd need to make your own dataframe cacher using globals().
It might look something like this:
def load_cache_df(filepath:str)->pl.DataFrame:
    if "df_cache" not in globals():
        globals['df_cache']={}
    if filepath not in globals()['df_cache']:
        globals()['df_cache'][filepath]=pl.read_parquet(filepath)
    return globals()['df_cache'][filepath]

You might need another function that deduces the filepath based on the UI inputs which is fine and maybe that gets cached by streamlit as those inputs would likely be hashable.
So then you'd have something like
@st.cache_resource
def derive_file_path(inputA, input_b):
   return f"{inputA}/{input_b} # or whatever it is

@st.cache_resource
def slow_function(inputA, input_b): 
   df = load_cache_df(derive_file_path(inputA, input_b))
   return df.group_by(inputA).agg(pl.col('cool_data').sum())

